# trying to deploy react project but having issues

Tags: deployment, netlify

I am trying to deploy my react project on netlify, i am getting page not found error. but on the vercel  it is deployed successfully, all the routes are working perfectly. what will be the issue ?added all the environment variables on netlify still getting this "Page Not Found
Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site." & also added netlify.toml file ...

Trying to deploy React Project

Comment: Please include what react bundle you're including, are you using Next.js? Can you provide a repository that demonstrates the problem? We will need to know if you're just using plain react with react-dom, or if you're using Next.js, what version of Node.js are you running and what does your Netlify setup look like for the project?